# Autoboxing isnt working properly

Tags: java, eclipse, autoboxing

I am trying to implement autoboxing but it's showing an error:

> Cannot convert from int to integer.

```
package JavaTraining;
public class Wrap { 
    public static void main(String ar[])
    {
        Integer a=100;
        String i=a.toString();
        System.out.println(i);
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

Eclispe version is 3.1

Comment: Please put your code in the question.  Also, what version of the compiler?

Comment: package JavaTraining;



public class Wrap {


 
 public static void main(String ar[])
 {
  Integer a=100;
  String i=a.toString();
  System.out.println(i);
  System.out.println(a);
 }
 

}

Comment: @SLaks i have included the code in the question as well as the version

Comment: @Saravana Type mismatch,Cannot convert int to integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This is relevant to Eclipse specifically) -
 You need to change your Compiler compliance level to **at least 1.5**.

> Project -> Properties -> Java Compiler -> Compiler compliance level

[image]

Comment: thanks.it was 1.4 earlier, now i have set it to 5.0 and its working properly