# how to add int value to Set<Integer> (HashSet<Integer>)?

Tags: java, generics, collections, integer

I created a set and a random number (type of int) that I want to add to my set:

```
private Set<Integer> mySet = new HashSet<Integer>(numElements); // capacity of 'numElements'

Random r = new Random();
int rand = r.nextInt(maxVal - minVal + 1) + minVal;
mySet.add(rand); // error: cannot convert int to Integer
```

so I tried these:

```
1. mySet.add(rand); // error: no suitable method found for add(int)
2. mySet.add(Integer.valueOf(rand)); //error: cannot find symbol method valueOf(int)
3. mySet.add(new Integer(rand)); // error: type parameter Integer cannot be instantiated directly
```

They all don't work so how can I add 'rand' to my set?

Comment: You should post the *complete* code. Obviously, you have a type named `Integer` in your scope, which is different to `java.lang.Integer`. According to the last error message, it is a type parameter, declared either at the method or at the class containing your code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Autoboxing isnt working properly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38464664/autoboxing-isnt-working-properly)

Answer (score 1):

You must create object of type Integer:

```
Integer intObj = new Integer(i);
```

being `i` an `int` type.

So in your example, it would be something like:

```
private Set<Integer> mySet = new HashSet<Integer>(numElements); // capacity of 'numElements'

Random r = new Random();
int rand = r.nextInt(maxVal - minVal + 1) + minVal;
mySet.add(new Integer(rand));
```

Comment: but when I try this: mySet.add(new Integer(rand)); it doesn't work. It's written that "type parameter Integer cannot be instantiated directly".

and it doesn't work even if I do this:

Integer iRand = new Integer(rand);
mySet.add(iRand);

Comment: ohh I just saw your edit.. so I must create MyInteger class that extends Integer for adding int to Set<Integer>?

Answer (score 0):

I succeeded to find a solution that solves the problem of all the collections that you try to add them a 'int' value.  I created this class:

```
class Number {
    int number;
    Number(int num) { number = num; }
}
```

Then, in my code, I used it:

```
Number number = new Number(index); // index is int type
mySet.add(number); // adding an object into a collection is legal
```

Comment: Adding an object of your custom type `Number` to a `Set<Integer>` is *not* legal. If that is accepted by the compiler, you have changed the type of your `Set` beforehand. This is kludging as it doesn’t solve your initial task of creating a `Set<Integer>`.

Comment: you're right. I forgot to write it but I changed the Set type from Integer to Number.